# Nginx bad gateway error on some methods while other works

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx

I am running Django on nginix but one of my functions is returning this error:

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

While other methods are working fine.

I have traied increasing server timeout in nginx.conf file but still it gives me the same error.
This methods runs fine whe i run my django independently with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Can someone help me to resolve it?

Comment: What application server are you using - gunicorn, uWSGI? Worth checking the application server log file after you reproduce the issue.

Comment: i am using gunicorn

Comment: Do the gunicorn logs show any errors when you reproduce the problem?